# Other ways to efficiently search within an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, if-statement, search

I started with this code except the comments:

```
mol1...;mol2...;
r1 = size(e, 1);%number of candidates for aligned amino acid
r0 = size(e0,1);%number of candidates for reference amino acid
for i = 1 : r1
    %if e(i, 1) > 4
        for j = 1 : r0
            %if e0(j, 1) > 4
                if e(i, 1) == e0(j, 1)
                    eI(i, j) = e(i, 1);%number of atoms matched
                    eT(i, j) = abs((e(i, 2) - e0(j, 2)) / e0(j, 2) * 100);
                    end
                %end
            end
        %end
    end
```

mol1 and mol2 are the combinations of selecting atoms and the total number: ex for a 3 atom molecule (1,   1,0,0) (1,   0,1,0) ... (3,   1,1,1).
e and e0 are some numbers regarding geometry.

When I get to more atoms the size of the array can be 200 000.
I thought that it wouldn't hurt to lose combinations of less than 5 atoms, but the code did not run faster.
So the problem is with the ifs.
Next I tried to delete combinations <5, keep the indexes and rebuild the initial array afterwards:

```
e (:, 7) = find(e (:, 1));
e0(:, 7) = find(e0(:, 1));
e (e (:, 4) < 5, :) = [];
e0(e0(:, 4) < 5, :) = [];
...
```

This halved the time.
I tic-toc-ed the code of 500 lines and the problem is here. It would take 2 years for 300 molecules (that I have chosen until now) and I would like to ad some more (20000).

So what other ways of scraping atoms in my array can you guys think of?
Maybe I should decide for each size of molecules (15 atoms can scrap results of 5 atoms; 8-4).
If changing the precision would reduce this time, how should I do it?

---

Version 2: cannot submit - webpage won't allow - see comments

---

Version 3 (50x faster than v2):

```
e(:,7)=find(e (:, 1));
e0(:,7)=find(e0 (:, 1));
[val,ia,ib]=intersect(e(:, 1), e0(:, 1));
for i = 1 : size(ia)
for j = 1 : size(ib)
eI(e(ia(i), 7), e0(ib(j), 7)) = e(ia(i), 1);
eT(e(ia(i), 7), e0(ib(j), 7)) = abs((e(ia(i), 2) - e0(ib(j), )) / e0(ib(j), 2) * 100);
end
end
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do in this loop? You don't use `mol1` and `mol2`, so I don't know how they fit into this. What are the sizes of `e` and `e0`? Can you provide a small sample of your data and the desired result?

Comment: @beaker I cannot edit the question...So this is version 2:
for mol1, e0=`1,eigenvalue-1, 1,0,0, something1;
    1,eigenvalue-2, 0,1,0, something2;
    .......;
    3,eigenvalue-n, 1,1,1, somethingn;
for mol2, e=1,eigenvalue-1, 1,0,0, something1;
    1,eigenvalue-2, 0,1,0, something2;
    .......
    3,eigenvalue-n, 1,1,1, somethingn;
in the first column, I have the number of atoms chosen;
in the second one, I have eigenvalues of the geometry for some chosen atoms;
3-5: indexes of chosen atoms;
6: I don't remember and the code is running;

Comment: continuing since I cannot edit the question: I was thinking of saving the indexes of rows before deleting some:
`e2=e;e02=e0;
e (:, 7) = find(e (:, 1));
e0(:, 7) = find(e0(:, 1));`
Now I delete rows and continue:
`e (e (:, 4) < 5, :) = [];e0(e0(:, 4) < 5, :) = [];
r1 = size(e, 1);
r0 = size(e0,1);
for i = 1 : r1
for j = 1 : r0
if e(i, 1) == e0(j, 1)
eI(e(i,7),e0(j,7) = e(i, 1);
eT(e(i,7),e0(j,7) = abs((e(i, 2) - e0(j, 2)) / e0(j, 2) * 100);
end
end
end`
Now I copy the back-up: `e=e2;e0=e02;`

Comment: for a sample I can provide this [article](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/13/10/1849) of mine that needs improvements

Comment: Of course you can edit the question, don't be silly. I'm not going to slog through code in comments or go to an external site to try to understand your problem.

Comment: @beaker I assure you what I pasted in the comments did not work after presing edit in the question. Thank you anyway. The fact that someone responded made me search some more and I am trying now to add version 3 - 50x faster. Still I would need to make the code faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a vectorized form that computes the result without any for loop:

```
e_eq_e0 = e(:, 1) == e0(:, 1).';

eI = e_eq_e0 .* e(:, 1);
eT = e_eq_e0 .* abs((e(:, 2) ./ e0(:, 2).'  - 1) * 100);
```

However the main problem in your code is that you don't pre-allocate the matrices `eI` and `eT` before using them:

```
eI = zeros(r1, r0);
eT = zeros(r1, r0);
for i = 1 : r1
....
```

Comment: Thank you, will try tomorrow. I need it to run even faster... Any other ideas are welcomed.

Comment: It is interesting that if I pre-allocate, I get zero results. I guess a kind of preallocation is also for `i = r1:-1:1`, which works. Your version is as fast as the one I found.

Comment: but your version gives the same results as the original... Care to find what I did wrong in ver 3, since the results of it are not the same with the rest?

Comment: I cannot say what is wrong, but I think that you should provide a minimum reproducible example with inputs and the expected outputs and try both loop and intersect methods to see witch one  actually you need.